# Circuit resistances with activating switches

Tags: resistors, resistance

Electronics beginner here - My current project is an automotive project whereby I want to recreate a small circuit which uses resistors to feed the car's ECU with information as to what action to take.

It consists of four switches which when pressed change the resistance of the circuit. I have measured the resistances with all five different possible scenarios and the results are as follows

```
(Default) No switches pressed - 3.96 kohms
SW1 pressed - 658 ohms
SW2 Pressed - 248 ohms
SW3 Pressed - 1477 ohms
SW4 pressed - 0 ohms
```

My question is how would I in practice wire the circuit to have a resistance of 3.96 kohms when all buttons are depressed yet have the relevant resistance when all the rest are pressed? The car needs to register the default resistance to avoid throwing up an error straight off the bat

Comment: Which one is the default case? What happens when SW1 and SW3 are pressed? Why do you want to have to press ALL FOUR of them? Four switches have 16 permutations. What do you want to happen in each one of these 16 permutations?

Comment: I take it you never need to go straight from 658 to 248 Ohms?

Comment: Okay. Since the switches are just momentary, I think you can follow the basic idea of the answer you were given. Do you follow that answer and are you able to calculate the resistor values that are required? The formula is easy: $$R_{{\mid\mid}_N}=\frac{R_N}{3.96\:\text{k}\Omega-R_N}\cdot 3.96\:\text{k}\Omega$$ Of course, this assumes that with no switches engaged there is already a \$3.96\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor and that each switch places the computed resistor value *in parallel* with that one.

Comment: I'll write something up that will help clarify things. Ask questions there.

Comment: In English, "depressed" often means the same as "pressed" - it is better to say "released" when you mean "not pressed".

Answer (score 1):

The entire circuit would probably look something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fap9m2m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The values I computed above came from this formula:

$$R_{{\mid\mid}_N}=3.96\:\text{k}\Omega\left[\frac{R_N}{3.96\:\text{k}\Omega-R_N}\right]$$

where \$R_N\$ is the desired total resistance that you provided in your question and where \$R_{{\mid\mid}_N}\$ is the computed value to use in the circuit, as shown above.

I've used exact values, which in general are not available exactly as shown. But they can be fabricated out of pairs of resistors, if need be.

Now take a look at this chart (borrowed from [here](https://www.vishay.com/docs/28372/e-series.pdf)):

[image]

This lists all of the possible 2-digit and 3-digit resistor values you can get. The E3 are \$\pm 40\%\$, E6 are \$\pm 20\%\$, E12 are \$\pm 10\%\$, E24 are \$\pm 5\%\$, E48 are \$\pm 2\%\$, E96 are \$\pm 1\%\$, and E192 are \$\pm 0.5\%\$.

So, depending on how much accuracy you require, you may have to hunt around to find the right combinations. You can select two resistors from the list and place them in series to get the value you want.

For example, \$3.96\:\text{k}\Omega\$ can't be found in the above table. The closest you can find will be \$3.97\:\text{k}\Omega\$ in the E192 list. But E192 parts are more expensive, too. Regardless, one option is that you could simply accept the value you can get as an E192. It's probably close enough.

However, you might use \$3.96\:\text{k}\Omega=1.47\:\text{k}\Omega+2.49\:\text{k}\Omega\$, where those two resistor values on the right side can be found as either E96 parts (1%) or E48 parts (2%), which are much more common and less costly. Of course, the tolerance is also wider, too.

The same goes for \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$, and \$R_3\$. If you can't find an exact match in the above table and if you want to go to the extra effort to get as close as possible, you can compose those values using pairs of other values to get there. More resistors. But they are cheap.

Of course, you may not need to be anywhere near that precise for your use. Only you know, for sure. But those are some ways to go.

Finally, I think you can see that pressing \$SW_4\$ will indeed cause \$0\:\Omega\$. It shorts out \$R_5\$ so that the resistance between \$T_1\$ and \$T_2\$ will be \$0\:\Omega\$ when \$SW_4\$ is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You could just hook up the different resistors to a 5 position switch. The image below is of a 12 position rotary switch but others are out there.

[image: 12 position switch]

Comment: A rotary switch is not what I'm after as the buttons required are momentary and the change in resistance to the desired ohmage is what the vehicle uses to make the command

Comment: Then just connect each switch with a resistor is parallel to the 3.96K resistance. Choose a resistance value that gives you the required parallel resistance. A 790ohm resistor in parallel with the 3.96K will give you 658.6ohms.